# How does Trim differ between VBA and Windows Service(VB.Net)?

Tags: vba, vb.net, trim, adodb

I'm currently creating a Windows Service(VB.Net) using a VBA which already has been implemented many years ago. Some of the code I do not understand and would really appreciate if anyone can make it simpler to understand and explain.

strOrderNo = Trim(rs1("work_order") & "")

Here rs1 is a ADODB Recordset, I understand that part but I do not get what's done by **& ""** part.

Thank you!

Comment: it is making sure the value returned is a string and not a number `1 & ""` will return `"1"`.  it changes the Int to a String.

Comment: Or just trying to *convert* a null value into an empty string.

Comment: The `Trim` function in VB.NET, if taken from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` "legacy back-compat" namespace, does not differ. It strips leading and trailing spaces from a string, is all. `&` is the string concat operator, that concatenates two strings; here it looks like it's being used as a lazy substitute for Access' `Nz` function, because concatenating an empty string to a `NULL` will yield an empty string, which probably prevents a *type mismatch* error if `strOrderNo` is declared `As String` as its Hungarian-Notation prefix suggests.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon since you've mentioned Access Nz function I googled that. Also I found this code added as a separate module in the VBA. That looks like Nz funtion to me, what do you think? Thanks
Code ====> 

Function FXA(str1, Optional allownull As Boolean = False) As String
    str1 = IIf(IsNull(str1), "", RTrim(str1))
    FXA = Replace(str1, "'", "''")
    If Trim(FXA) = "" And allownull = True Then
        FXA = "Null"
    Else
        FXA = "'" & FXA & "'"
    End If
End Function

Comment: It does look like it. Except `IIf` is a function though, so VBA must evaluate all its arguments before it can invoke it, which means `RTrim(str1)` is actually doing the very same implicit conversion it's trying to prevent, because of accidental assumptions about the implementation of `RTrim` that would stick out if `str1` was named `unverifiedInput` instead; best expand that `IIf` into a proper `If...Then...Else...End If` block IMO.