# What is the purpose this code "SomeString" & ""=""

Tags: vb.net

I come across this code "SomeString" & ""="" on a vb.net application.

May I know what is the coding logic on this? It seem to be evaluate the "SomeString" is empty or not which return true or false.

[image]

Comment: See the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67219056/7444103) (could be replaced by `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(...)`)

Comment: are you just seeing that in the debugger? the debugger i believe has its own syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice the multiple quotes around the `=` character? Your expression is a string comparison. It first concatenates `"SomeString"` with and empty string (the first two double quotes). The result is `"SomeString"`. Then this result is compared with the empty string (the last two double quotes). The `=` character serves as [equality comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators). The result of the expression is `False` because `"SomeString"` doesn't equal to `""`.

To better understand, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
("SomeString" & "") = ""
```

And yes, as already mentioned in one comment, the original purpose of your code was probably to test whether a string is empty or Nothing. I assume that in your real case, some variable `someString` is used instead of the literal string `"SomeString"`. The first part of the expression:

```
someString & ""
```

will ensure that the result is the original `someString` or an empty string if the `someString` was `Nothing` (null). And this is compared to an empty string. The correct way is to replace the original expression

```
someString & "" = ""
```

with the following:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` between strings in VB.NET is string concatenation.

Comment: Yes. I understand & is concatenation. But I not understand why "SomeString" & ""="" return a false.